# Plotting event density in Python with ggplot and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, python-ggplot

I am trying to visualize data of this form:

```
  timestamp               senderId
0     735217  106758968942084595234
1     735217  114647222927547413607
2     735217  106758968942084595234
3     735217  106758968942084595234
4     735217  114647222927547413607
5     etc...
```

`geom_density` works if I don't separate the `senderId`s:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')
df.columns = ['timestamp', 'senderId']
plot = ggplot(aes(x='timestamp'), data=df) + geom_density()
print plot
```

The result looks as expected:

[image: density plot]

**However if I want to show the `senderId`s separately, [as is done in the doc](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/geom_density.html), it fails:**

```
> plot = ggplot(aes(x='timestamp', color='senderId'), data=df) + geom_density()
ValueError: `dataset` input should have multiple elements.
```

**Trying out with a larger dataset (~40K events):**

```
> plot = ggplot(aes(x='timestamp', color='senderId'), data=df) + geom_density()
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

**Any idea?** There are some answers on SO for those errors but none seems relevant.

This is the kind of graph I want (from ggplot's doc):

[image: density plot]

Comment: I know this is odd, but does anything different happen if you specify `colour` instead of `color`?

Comment: I find it hard to understand if there is a ggplot package in Python, based solely on the posts in this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the smaller dataset:

```
> plot = ggplot(aes(x='timestamp', color='senderId'), data=df) + geom_density()
ValueError: `dataset` input should have multiple elements.
```

This was because some `senderId`s had only one row.

With the bigger dataset:

```
> plot = ggplot(aes(x='timestamp', color='senderId'), data=df) + geom_density()
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

This was because for some `senderId`s I had multiple rows at the exact same `timestamp`. This is not supported by `ggplot`. I could solve it by using finer timestamps.