# Plotting density plot with time dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I have a dataframe with a range of different format time stamps.

```
print df.head()

   Time              _datetime     time_stamp          hour     day  
0  00:00:00.0000000  1486339200000 2017-02-06 00:00:00     0  Monday  
1  00:00:00.0000000  1486339200000 2017-02-06 00:00:00     0  Monday  
2  00:00:00.0000000  1486339200000 2017-02-06 00:00:00     0  Monday  
3  23:59:59.0000000  1486339199000 2017-02-05 23:59:59    23  Sunday  
4  23:59:59.0000000  1486339199000 2017-02-05 23:59:59    23  Sunday 

Time                       object
_datetime                   int64
time_stamp         datetime64[ns]
hour                        int64
day                        object
```

I wish to plot a density plot:

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='_datetime'),data=df) + geom_density()
```

This works. However, when I add in a colour dissaggregation:

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='_datetime',color='day'),data=df) + geom_density()
```

I get:

```
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: singular matrix
```

I have tried:

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='time_stamp',color='day'),data=df) + geom_density()
```

Returning `TypeError: invalid type promotion`

This could be related to [Plotting event density in Python with ggplot and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101519/plotting-event-density-in-python-with-ggplot-and-pandas)

Edit
If I change `day` from an object to an `int`:

```
df['day'] = df['time_stamp'].dt.weekday

p = ggplot(aes(x='_datetime',color='day'),data=df) + geom_density()
```

It returns:

`ValueError: RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4`